# Set Video Width an Height on full screen on all resolutions Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to set up video width and video height using JavaScript/jQuery. I need to obtain on a page load video to be set on full screen on any resolution. Here what i managed to do, but it doesn't work, I am new to JavaScript or jQuery but I think the logic of code is correct. Thank you for your time!

HTML Code

```
<div id='videoContainer'>
  <video id = "video1" src="video/1v.mp4"> Test Video </video>
</div>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    var video1 = document.getElementById('video1') ;

    function playVideo()
    {
    video1.volume = 1 ; // Setting volume to maximum (Range : 0 to 1)
    video1.play() ;

    }
    video1.onload = playVideo() ;
    </script>
```

JavaScript CODE

I tried to do like this : `$('#video1').css({"width":screen.width, "height":screen.height});`

And like this:

```
sw=innerWidth;
sh=innerHeight;
$('#video1').css('width',sw);
$('#video1').css('height',sh);
```

Non of this worked.....

Comment: You could try $(window).height(); and $(window).width();

Comment: This will make all my elements to be set at max width and max height? I need only a video to be set like this after to the user to close it.

Comment: Or you could use `width=window.innerWidth;` `height=window.innerHeight;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code, it should work now:

```
<div id='videoContainer'>
  <video id="video1" src="video/1v.mp4"> Test Video </video>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function playVideo() {
   var video=document.getElementById("video1");
   video.width=window.innerWidth; 
   video.height=window.innerHeight;
   video1.volume = 1;
   video1.play();
}
video1.onload = playVideo();
</script>
```

You can try it here: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xGh0stSn1p3r/JvgNt/)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#video1").width($(document).width()).height($(document).height());`, using the [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to get the current computed width/height for the document and set that values for your video element. [JSFiddle working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q6p4s/)